# CMS architecture - which way to go?

Tags: php, design-patterns, zend-framework, architecture, content-management-system

For the past weeks I can't stop thinking about the **architecture of a CMS** I have to develop shortly. First of all I want to answer to the possible first questions that you could ask me.

1. **Q:** *Have you read the similar questions on StackOverflow?*
   **A:** Yes, I have. Unfortunately none applies to what I have to ask.
2. **Q:** *Why would you want to code **another** CMS???*
   **A:** Well, this is a bit of a long answer. Long story short: it has to be closed-source and it has to meet the requirements I need (it won't be 100% a CMS, it's a much more delicate subject - any project developed with it will be somewhere between 60-70% CMS and the rest will be custom code for that project's specific needs)
3. ***Tools of the trade:***

   - ***PHP***
   - ***Zend Framework*** (my personal choice; I'm very familiar with it and I won't change it for this task whatsoever)

### What I need this "CMS" to be

- **Developer oriented**

  Since it won't be a pure 100% CMS it *has* to be developer oriented - easy to maintain, easy to develop against (more like the feeling when developing on an enterprise level framework)
- **User/Editor oriented**

  While working on a project like this one, any programmer might find himself going in a wrong way and not thinking the person who'll work as an editor using this CMS is not in fact a very technical person. This is the part where conflicts happen - if it's not simple to use, yet powerful enough, you will have a lot of problems to deal with.
- **i18n** & **l10**

I'm almost certain it will be kind of a difficult task to code something both developer and user oriented and if I won't achieve this, I would like to give more importance to the **developer** instead of the editor. I am aware it's not a good deal to ignore the actual user of the software, but this CMS has to be fast to develop against.

### Possible architecture patterns

#### 1. General object

The first architectural design that got me thinking was the following:
I define a general object. The user/admin goes in the administration area and defines the data object he needs. Easy one.

The object `page` (for example) has a `title` field, a `body` field and a `slug`. It was just defined by the user and now he can create content based on this "data structure". Seems pretty neat, but I still didn't solve some of this architecture's problems.

- *How will those dynamic objects will be stored in the database? Should I use a `dataTypes` table, an `objects` table and link them many to many via `objectProperties` table?*
- *Or maybe should I serialize them and store everything in the `objects` table?*
- *Should I give the user the possibility to create new `dataType` properties and add them to its objects?*
- *How will I **i18n** all of this?*
- *Isn't too complicated to force the user to define its own data structures?*
- *Will it be too messy if it will have a lot of data structures defined, multiple languages? Would it be still manageable?*

#### 2. Extreme developer oriented - scaffold data structures

Today I found myself thinking about this possibility. It would be pretty neat to define the data structure of an object in a `yaml` or `ini` file and then scaffold it's database table, model and CRUD. Also mention it's relations to other "data structure" objects to get the right CRUD implementation (think about `page` data structure and `category` data structure, for example).

Unfortunately this made me also think about several possible problems.

- *Will I be able to code such a scaffolding tool on top of Zend Framework?* (which is known to be lacking scaffolding if we except the 2 or 3 suggestions made by the community, like [this one](http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFPROP/Zend_Controller_Scaffolding+-+Alex+Oroshchuk))
- *Is too stupid to create 2 tables for each object so I can internationalize it?*
- *Would it be too strict on the user if he can't define new data structures without the programmer?*

### Conclusion

I'm still very confused on how to approach this subject and what architecture to choose. At this very moment both are pretty challenging in terms of development.
My questions are pretty straight-forward.

#### If you would have to choose one of this approaches, which would it be and why?

#### Can you maybe suggest a more interesting pattern to follow, considering my needs?

Comment: from the faq: What kind of questions should I not ask here? ... every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?” http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: [Have you tried jargon?](http://www.dilbert.com/dyn/str_strip/000000000/00000000/0000000/000000/50000/4000/500/54565/54565.strip.gif)

Comment: @Dargon As you can easily see I'm not asking "what's your favorite ___?". I'm asking for a suggestion about the architectures I came up with or better suggestions based on my needs described above.

Comment: This should go to programmers.se

Comment: I am looking to build a novel CMS in PHP and I am facing these same questions you asked. Currently I am experienced in Javascript OOP and Angular. I'm just starting PHP so I need some advice on how to get started architecturing the CMS. I was going to ask you to share what you have learned, but being such a broad subject I'd like to discuss in person. I see you are located in Bucharest. If you are willing, I'd like to meet over a beer and get a good conversation about the subject.

Answer (score 2):

Just some general advice, if you are really trying to manage free-form *content* then I would stay away from relational databases for storing your data and go with an XML solution.  A relational database has too much structure for something that is purely content oriented.  Think of a home page...  You have info displayed like: welcome notice, about us, who we are.  That doesn't really map well to a table / collection of tables especially when you start adding / removing some of those items. Something with a defined structure, like stack overflow, does map well to a relation datbase however.

Take a look at Day CMS, Apache Sling, Java Content Repository for some ideas.

http://www.day.com/day/en.html

http://sling.apache.org/site/index.html

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_repository_API_for_Java

Answer (score 1):

From my point of view more options are always a problem. Users are mostly ignorant, when it comes to complex systems. Therefore I'd stick with the developer-oriented solution. Developer will decide what kind of content can be displayed. Optionally I would allow some kind of "open" content - for power users, allowing complex CSS/HTML/JS. Complex content like photo galleries, user profiles, etc. should not be designed by BFUs.

So to sum up - main feature - creating pages that can be dropped anywhere in the structure (that should be very flexible). If they want user profiles, you can create a new type of page. But at the end of the day, BFUs can do anything with enough time. It depends on the price/time scale. If they can pay for it and need it fast, they will make you create a new user profile page type, taht will be easy to fill. If they are kinda poor, they'll choose to setup all by themselves using normal page and WYSIWYG :D

Comment: One of our client wanted ticket system for their CMS - really simple - ticket, asignee, opened/closed (i.e.: basecamp with worse UI). They would do jsut fine with basecamp and it will actually be more useable, but the *think* they need it in the CMS. So they have it ;) Needless to say where they were i the scale ;)